# Why does a declared property use both retain and readonly?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, declared-property

I've noticed that some of Apple's examples include both a `retain` and `readonly` modifier on properties. What's the point of including `retain` if no setter gets generated when we're using the `readonly` modifier?

Example: `@property (retain, readonly) NSString *title;` from the AnimatedTableView sample.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can include a second, private readwrite declaration in a class extension. The memory management scheme for all references needs to match IIRC, so you get silliness like "readonly, retain".

Comment: It isn't entirely silly;  the matrix of modifiers vs. @synthesize is such that the getter's code **can** change.  Trying to suss out exactly which modifiers should be able to be added vs. which should #warn would rife with minutia and hard to ultimately understand.  Better to simply go with "must be same except readonly->readwrite".

Answer (score 36):

Or, more specifically, (readonly, retain) enables a pattern like this:

Foo.h:

```
@interface StuffHolder:NSObject
@property(readonly, retain) MyStuff *stuff;
@end
```

Foo.m:

```
@interface StuffHolder()
@property(readwrite, retain) MyStuff *stuff;
@end

@implementation StuffHolder
@synthesize stuff;
@end
```

The end result is a property that is publicly readonly while being readwrite within the implementation and for whom both setter and getter are synthesized automatically by the compiler.

A warning *could* be generated in the case of no (readwrite, retain) override in the class extension -- something akin to `statement without an effect` -- but it would be more confusing than beneficial.  There are also a whole slew of different edge cases across the combinations that would equally warrant a warning, but don't really indicate an actual problem.  The decision was made to largely accept the various patterns without complaint for simplicity's sake (since they aren't correctness issues).

Comment: It's advertised as read-only but it will still be writeable if the compiler has generated a setter for it, wouldn't it?

Comment: If someone were to write the code to call the setter, sure, but without also declaring the method somewhere, they'll see a warning...

Comment: "Public" readonly  properties (declared in the header) and "private" retain properties (declared in the source file) are no longer supported (with Xcode 3.2.3 - iPhone SDK 4 and GCC 3.2)

error: synthesized properties 'x' and 'y' both claim ivar 'z'

Comment: They most certainly are supported.  Please file a bug if you are finding a particular pattern that isn't working (that should be)!  http://bugreport.apple.com/